# How to write image in <img> tag in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am concatenating my HTML in string now the HTML coming from my DB
also there some images stores in DB Both path and Bytes...
now i want to show my image in html `<img>` tag then i write it on doc file

Here is my code:

```html
if (ds.Tables[4].Rows.Count > 0)
{

    DataTable Dt_4 = ds.Tables[4];

    foreach (DataRow item in Dt_4.Rows)
    {
        QuestionName += "<br style='page-break-before: always'> <br style='page-break-before: always'>";
        QuestionName += "<b><span style='text-decoration:underline'>Question :  </span>" + Dt_4.Rows[0]["Q_Num"].ToString() + "</b>";
                                
        QuestionName += "<b><span style='padding-left:20px;'>Marks :  </span>(" + item["Marks"].ToString() + ")</b>";
        QuestionName += item["QuestionName"].ToString();

        string imagePath = item["ImagePath"].ToString();
                               
        QuestionName += " <div><img src='" + imagePath + "' height='350' width='450'> </div> ";
                             
    }                      
}
```

the image shows correctly when i run it on sever but when i access server from my local machine it doesn't show
any help ???

Comment: It is the most creative formatting of code I've ever seen.

Comment: Is item["ImagePath"] a local file path (on the server) or an HTTP URL?

Comment: actually m a new one in stackoverflow so cudnt format code in snippet...and i am fetching my server path sorry forget to add server.mappath

Comment: Follow up to adv12, what if you make the path a shared location? Can you take the imagePath and copy it, then paste it in file explorer on the local machine?

Comment: actually when i run my app from my local machine and access server it shows image server path...maybe i need also to download it first in local machine then show it

Comment: @naveedahmed, that's a bad way to go about it.  If you want to make the image available to any client machine, you need to set up a URL from which the file can be downloaded and use that in your `<img>` tag.  As for how to set up that URL, I've never used ASP.NET, but it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: That is to say, you need an ASP page (or whatever the right terminology is) that accepts parameters that identify the requested image, reads the correct image file from the local server, and streams it to the client.

Answer (score 4):

You can embed the images as Base64 encodes string, like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM0AAAD
 NCAMAAAAsYgRbAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5c
 cllPAAAABJQTFRF3NSmzMewPxIG//ncJEJsldTou1jHgAAAARBJREFUeNrs2EEK
 gCAQBVDLuv+V20dE....." alt="beastie.png">

    string MakeImageSrcData(string filename)
    {
        byte[] filebytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        return "data:image/png;base64," +Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
    }

<img src="<%=MakeImageSrcData("c:\path\to\my.png") %>" />
```

https://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/embedding-images-in-html-using-c/
http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/

Comment: `fs` should be disposed. The easiest way is to initialize it in a `using` statement. Even easier would be `var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(…`.

Comment: can i write this image in word doc ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I'd guess Word supports opening inline images in Html docs - just try id!

Comment: using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {

                    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {

                        string body = "<body style='font-family: Calibri;font-size:14pt'> <head></head> <div style='width:100%'>";

                        w.Write(body + QuestionName + "</div></body>");


                    }
                }